# C# Hold down mouse event

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent

I have a mousemove event that takes the position of the cursor and outputs it to two labels (X and Y), the value dynamically changes as I hover around.  I have a mousedown event that when clicked, the same values are outputted to a textbox.  How can I combine the mousedown and mousemove events so that when I hover AND hold down the mouse button, the textbox value dynamically changes as I move.

Comment: How about storing a variable that when the mouse is down, you set the variable e.g. IsMouseLeftButtonDown bool; When you move the mouse, you can check the variable and only set the textbox value if the test passes

Comment: Can you please, some more brief? you want to display the Mouse Move points or the Mouse Down points in the Text Box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can interrogate the mouse buttons in your Move event handler, i.e. :

```
void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        String tipText = String.Format("({0}, {1})", e.X, e.Y);
        trackTip.Show(tipText, this, e.Location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Track the mouse down and mouse up events to set a variable determining whether or not the mouse button is pressed (ie set in down unset in mouse up) then just check this variable in mouse_move

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons.aspx
for an example

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 private void OnMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {

        }
 }
```

like this and in second `if` you will have a condition when your mosue moved **and**  mouse *Left* button is down.